# Deploy with Jenkins into CentOS 7.5 using pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, centos, jenkins-pipeline, ssh-agent

I need help with pipeline jenkins deploy, I try to deploy a Java webapps from jenkins into CentOS, I always have this error :

> FATAL: [ssh-agent] Could not find specified credentials
>   [ssh-agent] Looking for ssh-agent implementation...
>   [ssh-agent] FATAL: Could not find a suitable ssh-agent provider
>   [ssh-agent] Diagnostic report
>   [Pipeline] // sshagent
>   [Pipeline] }
>   [Pipeline] // node
>   [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: [ssh-agent] Could not find a suitable ssh-agent provider.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the pipeline code and the entries in your crendentials store.

Comment: this is my script

Comment: node("master") {

    stage('checkout') {
    git 'https://github.com/javab2i/helloworld.git'
}

stage('compiling') {
    bat 'mvn clean compile'
}

stage('testing') {
    bat 'mvn test'
}

stage('packaging') {
    bat 'mvn package'
}


stage('archiving') {
    archiveArtifacts 'target/*.war'
}

sshagent(['Tomcat-test']) {
    sh 'scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no target/*.war my_user@x.x.x.x:/opt/tomcat/webapps'
}
}

Comment: i have just a private ssh_key, no other credentials

Comment: Put your additional information in your question, you can edit it. And don't forget to format it.

Comment: Is the last stage, i.e. the `scp` command working on the command line under the user jenkins is running?